# Probability of picking 2 numbers between 0 and 1 to be within 1/2 distance of each other?

Tags: probability, area, geometric-probability

**Problem:** What's the probability of picking 2 numbers, x & y, between 0 and 1 such that they will be within the distance of $\frac{1}{2}$ of each other?
In other words, $\Pr(\text{distance between x and y} \le \frac{1}{2})=?$
I solved the problem through a geometric approach by rewriting the probability as $\Pr(|x-y|\le \frac{1}{2})$ and graphing $|x-y|\le \frac{1}{2}$
From the graph, I calculated the red area to be 75%.
**Question:** What would be a non-geometric solution to this problem?
[image]

Comment: $1-\left(\int_0^{1/2}\int_{x+.5}^11\,dy\,dx+\int_{1/2}^1\int_0^{x-.5}1\,dy\,dx\right)$.

Comment: Any thoughts about the answers that have been posted, Avg?

Comment: I'm interested in the thought process of how you came up with the integrals. It seems like they're areas between the curves that still required graphing.

Comment: If $|x-y|<1/2$, then either $0\le x\le1/2$ and $x+.5\le y\le1$, or $1/2\le x\le1$ and $0\le y\le x-.5$. No graphing necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pick two numbers greater than $\frac12$, subtract $\frac12$ from the smaller of the two. If they are the same, subtract $\frac12$ from the first number. This is a bijection to the two numbers being over $\frac12$ apart.

The probability of this not happening is $1-\left(\frac12\right)^2=\frac34$.